# Apache RewtireRule doesn't save URL after redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm currently trying to make Apache RewriteRule. The main idea is a user type in a browser

```
sensors.com/erd-admin
```

Apache should redirect it to the address

```
158.22.22.14/erd-admin
```

But I get in a browser URL -

```
158.22.22.14/erd-admin
```

How to save the domain name in a browser?

The final URL should be -

```
sensors.com/erd-admin
```

I was trying to make it like:

RewriteRule ^erd-admin `http://158.22.22.14/erd-admin/$1` [P]

but always get IP address instead of the domain address.

Big thank you!

Comment: Well you're telling it to redirect to the IP address and you're using the proxy flag.. If you don't want that. Check for the IP using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` and redirect to domain.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of pain, I found how to implement it.

The first step is to create a CNAME record for the IP.

> 158.22.22.14 CNAME erd-admin.sensors.com

The second step is to add the rewrite rule to .htaccess:

> RewriteRule ^erd-admin(.*) http://erd-admin.sensors.com/erd-admin$1 [P]

The third step in Virtual host config add ProxyPassReverse

> ProxyPassReverse / http://erd-admin.sensors.com/

Thank you all.

Regards,